# How to to limit connections for the same host (setMaxPerRoute) using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager** for sending multiple GET/POST requests in parallel to following services:

(1) http://localhost:8080/submit
(2) http://localhost:8080/query

Both services are heavily used but the first service (1) has a higher priority.

I need to set **setMaxPerRoute** for service (1) so that it will consume 80% of available connections. 
The rest 20% limit will be allocated for the rest requests with longer timeouts (including service (2)). Here is my code:

```
    ...        
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager httpClientManager = 
                    new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

            httpClientManager.setMaxTotal(10);

            httpClientManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(2);

            HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost("http://localhost/submit",8080);
            HttpRoute submitRoute = new HttpRoute(httpHost);
            httpClientManager.setMaxPerRoute(submitRoute, 8);
    ...
```

The problem is that HttpHost apparently cannot be the same to differentiate among routes. In fact, two URL-s have the same host (http://localhost:8080), but different request pages. In the result, both services are used the same resources.

Is there any way to implement such a limitation for the same host?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

After suggestions from my co-workers I've found the solution.

We need to control the maximum number of connections so that when requesting URL (1) we have the pool with max 20 connections, whereas the rest type of requests including request (2) we have the pool with max 2 connections.

It can be solved by creating two different **HttpClient**  objects each one has its own **PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager**. The first manager is set with setMaxTotal=20, while the second with setMaxTotal=2.

Now each pool is has different limitations for the same domain.